# Which HTML elements imply word breaks?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am working on a Chrome extension which extracts all words from any visited page and adds markup to various words in the text. I can get the full text of the page using

`document.body.innerText`

and split the result into words, but this does not provide the critical information on where (i.e. in which DOM element/node) a given word was, needed for the purpose of adding markup. The same issue is present with using

`document.body.textContent`

and this furthermore has the drawback that it contains non-visible items such as script tag contents.

Thus, I have written an iterative function that basically steps through the DOM elements (in a depth-first traversal of the tree) and accumulates the text obtained from

`node.data`

where node is any TEXT node encountered; this allows me to record the mapping between character ranges in the resulting text, and corresponding nodes in the DOM, and the resulting string seems to exactly match that of document.body.textContent. (Also, this allows me to filter out script tags etc.)

The problem I am facing is that textContent does not break words correctly, and it is (perhaps?) ambiguous where word breaks should go. For example:

`<p>One paragraph</p><p>Next paragraph</p>`

yields the string "One paragraphNext paragraph", i.e. there is no separating character between the two elements, and my code would detect only 3 words, not 4. textContent goes this wrong (no space) while innerText gets it right (inserts whitespace).

Further, it is incorrect to always put in a space between nodes/elements, because:

`<p>This is an <em>inter</em>net, not an intranet.</p>`

should yield the word "internet" without a space in it (i.e. it should not be divided into two words). (The reasoning here is that in case the extension is looking for the word "internet" then this should be marked, and in case the extension is looking for the word "net" then this should not be marked, because to the user this displays as one word "internet".)

The 'innerText' property correctly returns the text with spaces or not as appropriate (it seems). How can I simulate that in my iterative approach which steps through the DOM? Is it well-defined which elements (or element combinations/transitions) introduce whitespace in the displayed text, and which do not? Is it a question of elements being displayed block or inline?

Comment: What about margins, paddings, invisible borders, transforms, etc.? What is your expected result with the `<em>inter</em>net` case? Something like `<mark><em>inter</em>net</mark>`, but not `<em><mark>inter</mark></em>net`?

Comment: There _are_ specifications about white spaces and javascript DOM traversing. Check the script at the end of this MDN entry https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace

Comment: The way `innerText` inserts whitespace is well-defined, and specified in [the HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute).

Comment: @user4642212 Good point. I edited the question to indicate that indeed, for the <em>inter</em>net case the desired result is to mark the entire word internet, and not pieces like just inter or net. As for margins, paddings, etc, I suppose the ultimate goal is to mark as a word if it appears to the user as a word (but this may be quite difficult to achieve and I'll settle for less).

Comment: @FranciscoCerdaSepúlveda Thanks, I'll need to take a closer look at the material you pointed to!

Comment: @Siguza Your suggestion to look at exactly how innerText inserts whitespace (as defined in the standard) is excellent. I'll have a careful look at that. I bet that's sufficient to get this sorted out, at least to a degree that is sufficient for my purposes. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have now taken the suggestions by FranciscoCerdaSepúlveda and @Siguza and looked at how whitespace is inserted (particularly the rules for innerText). They are a bit too complex for my case; in the end I opted for a fairly simple approach, which I detail in an answer I just posted. If you have the time, have a look at that answer and provide any comments that come to your mind. Anyway, thanks a lot for the assistance!

Comment: Since there has been no further discussion or comments, or alternative answers, I now accepted the answer I posted. I'll reconsider if any better answers are posted, or if it turns out there is some serious flaw in the code I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having taken a closer look at the [HTML standard for innerText](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute) (thanks again to [Siguza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2302862/siguza) for the suggestion), I am coming back to this issue now. The rules for innerText are somewhat involved, and much of those rules are not needed in my case since I am only interested in where word breaks occur and not interested in getting the line breaks correct. I also feel that, in my case, a simple solution that gets it right in 99 cases out of 100 is better than a complex solution which is correct in all cases. So, with that in mind, I created the following simple function:

```
function getNodeText(node) 
{
  // If we have nothing to process, return the empty string.
  if (!node) return '';
  
  // Is this a text node? If so simply grab the text from it.
  if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) return node.data;
  
  // If this was not a text node (see above) and it is not an element 
  // node then nothing further to do, just return an empty string.
  if (node.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) return '';
  
  // Some elements we do not want to handle at all. Just returning empty.
  const tagsToAvoid = ['SCRIPT', 'NOSCRIPT', 'STYLE', 'OBJECT', 'IFRAME'];
  if (tagsToAvoid.includes(node.tagName)) return '';    
  
  // A line break nodes simply inserts a space
  if (node.tagName == 'BR') return ' ';
  
  // Block-level tags 
  const blockTags = 
    ['ADDRESS', 'ARTICLE', 'ASIDE', 'BLOCKQUOTE', 'CANVAS', 'DD', 'DIV', 
     'DL', 'DT', 'FIELDSET', 'FIGCAPTION', 'FIGURE', 'FOOTER', 'FORM', 
     'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'HEADER', 'HR', 'LI', 'MAIN', 'NAV',
     'OL', 'P', 'PRE', 'SECTION', 'TABLE', 'TD', 'TR', 'TFOOT', 'UL', 
     'VIDEO', 'TBODY', 'THEAD', 'COL', 'COLGROUP', 'TH', 'CAPTION'];
  
  // Whether to add whitespace around the text that is obtained
  // from iterating over the children. In typical cases there is no 
  // whitespace inserted, but block level nodes do get whitespace.
  const addSpaces = blockTags.includes(node.tagName);
  
  // Step through all children and get the text from them (recursively)
  let child = node.firstChild;
  let textFromChildren = '';
  while (child)
  {
    textFromChildren += getNodeText(child);
    child = child.nextSibling;
  }
  
  // Return the result, with added whitespace or not
  if (addSpaces) return ' ' + textFromChildren + ' ';
  else return textFromChildren;
}
```

Note that, for clarity, I have left out the code which tracks which parts of the resulting string came from which nodes (this is easy to add to the above).

A few caveats:

(1) The code is slow. On long pages executing this can take tens of milliseconds, which can be about ten times slower than simply calling the standard innerText (which in turns is typically slower than textContent). I am not clear on whether there are easy ways to speed up the code; perhaps people wiser than me can comment on this.

(2) I think there are ways in which the above is not fully correct, because it does not take into account the styles (which for example can affect whether elements are displayed as block or inline). However, the hope is that this is good enough, for the vast majority of cases. (Again, others who have been working in this area longer than me are probably in a better position to say something about this.)